# Should I add kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0' when I Integrate Hilt with the Jetpack navigation library in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, dagger-hilt

I have read the article https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android, to use dependency injection with Hilt, I have modified my build.gradle files as Code A and Code B.

Now I hope to Integrate Hilt with the Jetpack navigation library, based on the article https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack, I have modified Code B with Code C.

Should I add `kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'` when I Integrate Hilt with the Jetpack navigation library in Android Studio in Code C?

**Code A （root build.gradle）**

```
plugins {
  ...
  id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false
}
```

**Code B  （app/build.gradle）**

```
   plugins {
      id 'kotlin-kapt'
      id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
   }
    
   android {
      ...
   }
    
   dependencies {
      implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
      kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44"
   }
```

**Code C （app/build.gradle）**

```
plugins {
  id 'kotlin-kapt'
  id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
}

android {
  ...
}

dependencies {
  implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
  kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.44"
  implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
  //  kapt 'androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0'     //Should I add ?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Hilt includes extensions for providing classes from other Jetpack libraries. Hilt currently supports the following Jetpack components:

- ViewModel
- Navigation
- Compose
- WorkManager

plugins {
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
}

```
android {
  ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-work:1.0.0")
    // When using Kotlin.
    kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")
    // When using Java.
    annotationProcessor("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0'
}
```

Please refer to this link:- https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack